# GEdit - Python Console plugin not retaining color settings

Tags: python, themes, gedit, plugins, colors

I was just fiddling around with GEdit and came across the Python Console in plugins section of it.

It would have been quite useful to do quick calculations while taking notes as I sometimes have to do.
But that utility was quickly rendered useless when the colors for commands and the errors were not visible at all on my overall dark theme.

I set the color preferences but they are not getting retained.

When I open the window, set the color, close it and reopen, the settings are back to default illegible colors.

[image: Default colors]

Any workaround or solution for this issue?

Comment: What versions of desktop and gedit are you running? Make sure to call gedit from command line to see any error messages there might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem for me, python console Preferences in plugin interface doing nothing, without any error message.

I finally changed the colors using gsettings in command line by typing the following commands in a terminal (pick your prefered colors, these are working for me).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole command-color '#0de0d6'
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole error-color '#FFD063'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already moved on to Ubuntu 20.04. So, this is no longer valid for me. If you say that this works, I am marking this as accepted answer so that others will benefit.

Comment: I did it on 20.04 myself, hencefore I can definitely confirm it works there.

Comment: Great work! Thanks a lot.